# Website Language - htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use rules and conditions with .htaccess but don't know how to do what I need.

Here's the scene:

I have a website with many languages. (en|es|pt)

I want to use the urls like this:

```
 www.site.com/home/ 
 (original url): www.site.com/index.php?p=home
 (opens home.php - session language)
```

And like this:

```
www.site.com/en/home/
(original url): www.site.com/index.php?l=en&p=home
(opens home.php - en language)
```

What are the eules/conditions that I need to create to detect the language in url?

TIA

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
RewriteRule ^(en|es|pt)?\/?([a-z0-9A-Z,_-]+)\/?$ index.php?l=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Note:
"current solution does also allow something like /enfoobar to be rewritten to /index.php?l=en&p=foobar as the / is independent of the language indicator" - Gumbo

Comment: mod_rewrite may not exactly be the answer to this one.  Take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html -- that may be more help than trying to use mod_rewrite for this.

Comment: Note that `[a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]` is equivalent to `[a-z0-9A-Z,_-]` and means *either `a`–`z`, `0`–`9`, `A`–`Z`, `,`, `_`, or `-`; the `,` is not a separator character but a regular character like the others.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `/`. Furthermore, your current solution does also allow something like `/enfoobar` to be rewritten to `/index.php?l=en&p=foobar` as the `/` is independent of the language indicator.

Comment: Yes. But if I don't escape it, the url (www.site.com/foobar/) wouldn't work. It's true, it will rewriten /enfoobar, but I don't know other way how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might probably use something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(en|es|pt)/(.*) /index.php?l=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For any 2digits characters languages

Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/index.html$ index.html?language=$1
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /index.php [L]